# Cast result findViewById android method

Tags: android, findviewbyid

Why do we always have to cast the value returned by the method `findViewById(id)` ? The method already returns a view, as I've seen in google reference :

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#findViewById(int)

Then is it possible to cast to another thing apart form a view ? For example, do this :

```
ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image) ?
```

Comment: yes casting is fine if you have imageview with id image in xml

Comment: sorry I cant understand the real question why do you need this

Comment: update, since android O api you are not required to cast the value anymore it is automatically done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method `findViewById()` returns an instance of the class that is actually used to define that view in your XML file. The method signature returns a `View` to make it generic and usable for all classes that inherit for `View`.

You need to cast the returned value to the class that your variable is defined when you use it like:

```
ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
```

Java won't cast that implicitly for you.

You could leave it as:

```
View image = findViewById(R.id.image);
```

but you wouldn't be able to use the methods, etc. defined on `ImageView` class.

Answer (score 16):

I always define a method which does the casting for me in my base activity:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public <T extends View> T $(int id) {
    return (T) findViewById(id);
}
```

This means instead of:

```
Button btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn);
```

You can do:

```
Button btn = $(R.id.btn);
```

Comment: Nice, ButterKnife does nearly the same thing, reducing the need to cast: [ButterKnife.findById(Activity, int)](http://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/javadoc/butterknife/ButterKnife.html#findById-android.app.Activity-int-)

Comment: Using Kotlin this is not needed any more, because they have internal binding of all views when layout is set, or if you still need this kind of method you can easily make extension function to the Activity class and write the logic there.

Answer (score 1):

`View` is the common superclass of other view classes such as `ImageView`. In object-oriented polymorphism, you can substitute a specific instance e.g. `ImageView` with the superclass. This is useful in generic APIs such as `findViewById()` return value.

Downcasting to a more specific type in Java requires an explicit cast.

Comment: @IanNewson Do you happen to have a counterexample where it is not needed?

Comment: @IanNewson I see an explicit cast `(T)`.

Comment: Yes, `null` can be assigned to any reference type without casting. But a `null` reference is not an object reference, and the issue was about casting object references down the inheritance tree.

Comment: I understand, but it still shows the last sentence to be incorrect. Anyway, I'll stop being pedantic now! :)

Answer (score 1):

We cast it to a particular view like ImageView or TextView when we need to use certain properties pertaining to those type of views. For example, you will use

```
ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
```

and then use `image` to set some properties of an ImageView explicitly. For instance,

```
image.setImageBitmap();
image.setImageAlpha();
```

and the like.
When you don't need to use any specific properties for the view, then no need of casting. For instance, in Android any view can be set visible, gone or invisible. In that case there is no need of type casting. Even the following will work.

```
View image = findViewById(R.id.image);
image.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `findViewById()` returns `View`. You can omit casting if you don't need to use the methods of any direct/indirect subclasses, that extends `View`, such as `ImageView`, `LinearLayout`, `TextView` etc.

`View` is the base class for widgets, which are used to create interactive UI components (buttons, text fields, etc.)

And of course you can downcast to any subclass of `View`